# Copy to output directory not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have website project with a publish profile set up to publish to ~\www\Website (the project source folder is ~\Website)

There is an .xml file in ~\Website\bin that is included in the project (it's the only file from the \bin folder that is) which is required for the CMS (Sitecore).

Looking at the included file's properties menu, Build Action is set as **Content** and Copy To Output directory is set as **Copy Always**.

When I run the publish, the file is not copied to ~\www\Website\bin but instead is placed in ~\www\Website\bin\bin.

I've tried changing the "Items to deploy" in the projects Package/Publish properties to "All files in this project" as describe [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd434211.aspx/) but the result does not change.

This is quite vexing and I've not been able understand why it occurs. Does anyone have any insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic behind "Copy always/if newer" is that the subdirectory structure is preserved when the files are copied to the output directory. Files that are located in subdirectories of your project are copied into the output directory in the same subdirectory structure.

```
ProjectDir\a.txt        -> OutputDir\a.txt
ProjectDir\Subdir\b.txt -> OutputDir\Subdir\b.txt
```

By default, the bin-directory is the output directory of a web application. So if you put the file into the bin-subdir then it will be copied into bin\bin as you describe.

In order to solve this, move the file to the project directory. It will be copied to the output directory (bin) without a subdirectory.

Comment: I've tried as you suggest (moved file to project directory ~\Website) but when I publish it is copied into ~\www\Website\ not ~\www\Website\bin\

Comment: @user3188426 What settings does the file have for *Build action* and *Copy to output directory*?

Comment: Tried as you suggest (moved file to project directory ~\Website) but on  publish it's copied into ~\www\Website\ not ~\www\Website\bin\. We inherited this solution, it's set up in an odd way so there may be some other setting that is causing this. According to the CMS vendor notes the file is required as part of a security patch. I spoke to other members in my team who implemented the patch  elsewhere it appears it's not required. One implementation has the file included in the published output and another doesn't but they both work correctly

Comment: Build Action is set as Content and Copy To Output directory is set as Copy Always.

Comment: If you set the Build Action to "None" it will not be copied to the root folder; maybe a rebuild helps to copy it to the bin-folder.

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm going to park this one for the time being.